# Python regex matching when it should not

Tags: python, regex, python-2.6

I have a list of strings and I want to print out the ones that don't match the regex but I'm having some trouble. The regex seems to match strings that it should not, if there is a substring that starts at the beginning of the string that matches the regex.  I'm not sure how to fix this.

Example

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\d+')
>>> string = u"1+*"
>>> bool(pattern.match(string))
True
```

I get true because of the `1` at the start.  How should I change my regex to account for this?

Note I'm on python 2.6.6

Comment: Your regex matches numbers, and the string contains a number. You already received some answers based on the hypothesis that you don't want strings which contain anything else, but whether this is really the case is not clear from your question. Perhaps you should [edit] it to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your regex start with `\A` and end with `\Z`. This will make sure that the match begins at the start of the input string, and also make sure that the match ends at the end of the input string.

So for the example you gave, it would look like:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\A\d+\Z')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should append `\Z` to the end of the regex, so the regex pattern is `'\d+\Z'`.

Your code then becomes:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\d+\Z')
>>> string = u"1+*"
>>> bool(pattern.match(string))
False
```

This works because `\Z` forces matching at only the end of the string. You may also use `$`, which forces a match at a newline before the end of the string or at the end of the [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). If you would like to force the string to only contain numeric values (irrelevant if using `re.match`, but maybe useful if using other regular expression libraries), you may add a `^` to the front of the pattern, forcing a match at the start of the string. The pattern would then be `'^\d+\Z'`.

Comment: I know. If they change the code to `re.search` though, it's not (but then re.search is pointless). Just added mostly for completeness, because most regular expression libraries work differently (like my favorite library, `re2`).